# Configuring Kafka Client One Way SSL with PEM

Tags: java, ssl, apache-kafka

I am trying to configure one way SSL for my kafka client using PEM. For now I'm experimenting with `kafka-topics.sh --list` but in the future it will be a Java client that cannot use JKS. The error message is telling me to specify the type, but the docs I'm referencing don't tell me how: https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#producerconfigs_ssl.truststore.certificates

> ssl.truststore.certificates
>
> Trusted certificates in the format specified by 'ssl.truststore.type'. Default SSL engine factory supports only PEM format with X.509 certificates.
>
> Type: password
> Default:  null
> Valid Values:
> Importance:   high

Below is the error message from kafka-topics.sh

```
~/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh \
  --command-config /home/kafka/kafka/client_security_one_way_ssl_using_pem.properties \
  --bootstrap-server MY_IP:9093 \
  --list
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to create new KafkaAdminClient
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient.createInternal(KafkaAdminClient.java:535)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.Admin.create(Admin.java:65)
        at kafka.admin.TopicCommand$AdminClientTopicService$.createAdminClient(TopicCommand.scala:228)
        at kafka.admin.TopicCommand$AdminClientTopicService$.apply(TopicCommand.scala:232)
        at kafka.admin.TopicCommand$.main(TopicCommand.scala:59)
        at kafka.admin.TopicCommand.main(TopicCommand.scala)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidConfigurationException: SSL trust store certs can be specified only for PEM, but trust store type is JKS.
```

Contents of `client_security_one_way_ssl_using_pem.properties`:

```
ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm=
security.protocol=SSL

ssl.truststore.certificates=-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- \
< SECRET :) > \
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

I also tried adding

```
ssl.truststore.type=PEM
```

but now my error message is:

```
[2021-03-10 16:18:21,343] WARN The configuration 'ssl.truststore.certificates' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig)
[2021-03-10 16:18:21,344] WARN The configuration 'ssl.truststore.type' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig)
[2021-03-10 16:18:21,344] WARN The configuration 'ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig)
```

These properties should be supported in 2.7.0:

```
~/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh   --version
2.7.0 (Commit:448719dc99a19793)
```

Answer (score 3):

Root cause was I needed to have

```
ssl.truststore.type=PEM
```

in my properties file.

The `WARN` log messages are not an issue. Apache Kafka is tracking the bug here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-10090 and fixed as of 2.8.0.

```
[2021-03-10 16:18:21,343] WARN The configuration 'ssl.truststore.certificates' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig)
[2021-03-10 16:18:21,344] WARN The configuration 'ssl.truststore.type' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig)
[2021-03-10 16:18:21,344] WARN The configuration 'ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig)
```

It was actually obtaining the topics, but I had no topics.